# Replacing <input name="city" type="text" /> with $_POST['city'] dynamically

Tags: php, html

I've been two days searching how to do this. I have this form:

```
<form action="preview.php" method="post">
In the city of <input name="city" type="text" /> at <input name="days" type="text" /> days of <input name="month" type="text" /> gathered the following people: <input name="name1" type="text" /> and <input name="name2" type="text" /> with the objective of...

<button type="submit">Preview</button></form>
```

And preview.php should have this:

```
In the city of <?php echo $_POST['city'];?> at <?php echo $_POST['days'];?> days of <?php echo $_POST['month'];?> gathered the following people: <?php echo $_POST['name1'];?> and <?php echo $_POST['name2'];?> with the objective of...
```

The thing is the form is created via CMS so I have no way of knowing what the names of the inputs will be.
Is there a way to dinamically replace, for example, `<input name="city" type="text" />` with `<?php echo $_POST['city'];?>`?
There are some thing I have in mind but since I'm new to PHP I don't know how to implement them.

Maybe `preg_replace` could do it but I don't know how to prevent the name of the input from changing.
Or maybe I could use an array, for example `<input name="data[]" type="text" />` and something like:

```
for($i=0;"";$i++){

if( isset( $_POST["data{$i}"] )) {

$string = $form;
$patterns = '<input name="data[]" type="text" />';
$replacement = $_POST["data{$i};
preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);

}

}
```

I'm really lost here and I'd appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

PS: I'm not a native english speaker son I'm sorry if I made some mistake.

UPDATE:
The user can make different forms in the CMS that will be saved in a database. Then he can choose which one he wants to fill. Once he fills it he can preview it and save it as a pdf.
The preview.php will have the same text in the form but instead of the inputs it will have the value that the user entered.

Comment: And why exactly wont you know what the field names are? Can't you just view the source?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do....

Comment: exactly how would you handle the "In the city" text? That's not going to be sent over with the form submission. All you'll get are the input/textarea fields from the form. If you can't know in advance what the fields are, you're almost certainly not going to know what text the fields are embedded in either.

Comment: +1 to the guys above me. You need to know what the fields are going to be called. If there’s a CMS involved you certainly will have a way to specify that when building the form or at least view the source code in the browser after it’s made to see what the CMS is calling those fields.

Comment: MaKe it `in the city of <?php echo $_POST['city']'?> ...`

Comment: you're new to PHP and are implementing a CMS. I hear some bells ringing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(I have been a bit out of touch with PHP.)*

Capture the HTML of the form with ob_ functions (output buffer).

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' {

    ob_start();

    ... the CMS outputs HTML

    ob_end_flush();
    $s = ob_get_contents();
```

Use the name attribute to replace things

```
    function postText($matches) {
       return $_POST[$matches[1]];
    }

    $s = preg_replace_callback('/<[^>]* name="([^">]+)"[^>]*>/',
        "postText",
        $s);
    echo $s;
```

This uses a function for replacing a HTML tag with a name attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it gives me this error `Warning: preg_replace_callback() [function.preg-replace-callback]: Unknown modifier ']'`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you SO much! I only did a little modification to the regex (from `<[^>]* name="([^">]+)"[^>]*>` to  `/<[^>]* name="([^">]+)"[^>]*>/`) and it worked great!

Comment: Thanks, added the slashes to the answer for others.